# How can I union with another table linq

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have this linq query I have been working on endlessly:

```
var complaintHistory = from histories in DbContext.Histories
                                       where (histories.Action_Date > Complaint.Date_Created_On && (from c in taskIds
                                               select "<Task_ID=" + c + ">").Contains(histories.Primary_Key) ||
                                              (from c in notificationListIds
                                               select "<Notification_List_ID=" + c + ">").Contains(histories.Primary_Key) ||
                                              (from c in emailSentIds
                                               select "<Email_Sent_ID=" + c + ">").Contains(histories.Primary_Key) ||
                                                  histories.Primary_Key == "<Complaint_ID=" + Complaint.Complaint_ID + ">") &&
                                                  histories.Field_Name != "rowversion"
                                       select histories;
```

I'm trying to figure out how to make that linq query more like this sql statement:

```
select * from etc.History as c where 
primary_key in 
(
select '<Task_ID=' + cast(Task_ID AS nvarchar) +  '>'
from  etc.Task
where Complaint_ID = 1209

UNION

select '<Notification_List_ID=' + cast(Notification_List_ID AS nvarchar) +  '>' 
from [etc].[Notification_List] 
where Complaint_ID = 1209                --where Notification_List_ID = 4479
UNION

select '<Email_Sent_ID=' + cast(Email_ID AS nvarchar) +  '>'
from [etc].[Email_Sent]
where Complaint_ID = 1209
UNION
SELECT '<Complaint_ID=' + cast(1209 AS nvarchar) +  '>')
  AND
   Field_Name!='rowversion'
```

I'm trying to improve the performance of the linq query so I'm trying to union "taskid" to the task table so I can use the where clause "complaint ID" to narrow the scope of my query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LINQ does provide a [`Union`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb341731(v=vs.100).aspx) method. That should get you started. I'd also suggest cleaning things up a bit so the code is more readable:

```
var tasks = // LINQ Query for Task_ID
var notifications = // LINQ Query for Notification_List_ID
var emails = // LINQ Query for Email_Send_ID and Complaint_ID

var union = tasks.Union(notifications).Union(emails);

DbContext.Histories.Where(h => 
    h.Action_Date > Complaint.Date_Created_On &&
    (union.Contains(h.Primary_Key) ||
        h.Primary_Key == "<Complaint_ID=" + h.Complaint_ID + ">") &&
    h.Field_Name != "rowversion");
```

Answer (score 0):

@Justin Niessner is right. But yaou can call multiple selects and concat them with `Enumerable.Concat<T>` method.